# How to check created_at exists or not between two date

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I have two dates. I want to check that created_at is existed or not between two dates that I will provide.

```
$form_date = 08/07/2018 // ('m/d/Y')
$to_date   = 08/014/2018 // ('m/d/Y')
```

I have tired

```
Model::whereBetween('created_at', [$form_date, $to_date])->get();
```

But it returns empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can solve this by do the following:

```
    $form_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y',$request['form_date'])->format('d-m-Y');
    $to_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y',$request['to_date'])->format('d-m-Y');
    Model::whereBetween('created_at', [$form_date, $to_date])->get();
```

Comment: Input 08/07/2018 ----
08/29/2018 output
2018-07-08 07:02:44 ----
2020-05-08 07:02:44 return wrong result

Comment: I am trying to format this two date. 08/07/2018 and
08/24/2018 the result is 08-07-2018 and
08-12-2019. first is ok. but the second one properly is not formatted.

Comment: this date wrong 08/24/2018 the format d/m/Y not m/d/Y

Comment: if your format m/d/Y then change the format in this createFromFormat('d/m/Y',$request['form_date'])  to createFromFormat('m/d/Y',$request['form_date'])

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your boundary dates into an ISO format which MySQL can directly use:

```
$from_date = '2018-08-07';
$to_date   = '2018-08-14';

Model::whereBetween('created_at',
                    [new Carbon($from_date), new Carbon($to_date)])->get();
```

Comment: I don't want to change date format 08/07/2018 to 2018-08-07. Is it not possible?

Comment: I think it would be possible to handle that either on the PHP or MySQL side, but it's not desirable, because it is a non standard difficult-to-use date format.